What are the benefits of all the d-links in KH Birth by Sleep?
In Kingdom Hearts: Birth by Sleep, what are the benefits of all the d-links and what do the different levels do?

If the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick

While the player character is using a D-Link, defeated enemies have a chance of dropping a special emblem that can be collected to raise the D-Link's level, expanding its Command Deck and unlocking a unique ability, as represented by the symbols to the left of the linked companion's sprite. Bringing the link up to Level 2 expands the deck again, adds a second ability, and grants access to a more powerful Finish command. Once a D-Link has reached Level 2, any additional emblems collected simply restore the D-Link Gauge.
You can find more information here.

